# Filter list of objects based on condition

Tags: c#, string, linq, lambda

```
public Class Car 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Color {get;set;}
}

Car1 = new {"Ford", "White"}
Car2 = new {"Ford Fiesta", "Blue"}
Car3 = new {"Honda City", "Yellow"}
Car4 = new {"Honda", "White"}

var carObj = new List<Car>();

carObj.Add(Car1);
carObj.Add(Car2);
carObj.Add(Car3);
carObj.Add(Car4);
```

I need to filter output based on car names, so that if a name is a subset of any names present, it will remove them.

Output:

```
Car2 = new {"Ford Fiesta", "Blue"}
Car3 = new {"Honda City", "Yellow"}
```

Here is what I am writing to do this, but it is not giving me the desired output.

```
// Remove duplicare records.
var carObjNEW = new List<Car>();
carObjNEW = carObj;

carObj.RemoveAll(a => carObjNEW.Any(b => a.Name.Contains(b.Name)));
```

Any help on how to fix this.

Comment: Have you looked at the `.Distinct()` command with `LINQ`?

Comment: `RemoveAll` does not modify the input, you have to reassign carObj with the result. Also, the output will be empty as every single car is already in comparison list.

Comment: Distinct will just do exact match, what I need is a substring match.

Comment: @ja72 notice how desired output is no simple duplicate removal.

Comment: So it removes the generic names and keeps the specific models?

Comment: @ja72 - If a list has "Ice Cream", and other has  "Cream" , and other have "Ice"...The last 2 will be removed. As "Ice Cream" covers the full information.

Comment: Well, you have a simple mistake: `carObj.RemoveAll(a => !carObjNEW.Any(b => a.Name.Contains(b.Name) && a.Name.Length > b.Name.Length));`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria - This seems to be working, but it is only getting me 2 words...if there is a single entry "Chevrolet" its removing that for no reason.

Comment: Yes, I see it. Just try it: `carObj.RemoveAll(a => carObjNEW.Any(b => b.Name.Contains(a.Name) && b.Name.Length > a.Name.Length));`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria This works perfect, just need to add case insensitive comparision. Please add this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comment you have a simple mistake. You need to remove item if list has another item that contains the first item as a substring:

```
carObj.RemoveAll(a => carObj.Any(b => b.Name.ToLower().Contains(a.Name.ToLower()) && b.Name.Length > a.Name.Length));
```

If you want to compare by `StringComparison`, just swap `Contains` to `IndexOf(String value, StringComparison comparisonType) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to work with two lists. Just put this:

```
carObj.RemoveAll(a => 
    carObj.Any(b => b.Name.Contains(a.Name) && b.Name.Length > a.Name.Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

project it and then filter

`carObj.Select(c => new { c, Match = carObj.Any(cc => cc.Name != c.Name && cc.Name.Contains(c.Name))}).Where(n => !n.Match)`